# Zend Framework 2 Module Index content not rendering

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have created a Client module in my ZF2 application and am using ServiceManager as suggested in [ZF2 Read The Docs](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/database-and-models.html).  My model class is as follows:

```
<?php 
namespace Client\Model;
class Client
{
public $id;
public $familyname;
public $businessname;

public function exchangeArray($data)
 {
    $this->id =(!empty(['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
    $this->familyname=(!empty(['familyname'])) ? $data['familyname'] : null;
    $this->businessname(!empty(['businessname'])) ? $data['businessname'] : null;
 }
}
```

My `ClientTable.php` contains:

```
namespace Client\Model;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class ClientTable
{
    protected $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function fetchAll()
    {
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
        return $resultSet;
    }

    public function getClient($id)
    {
        $id = (int) $id;
        $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('id' => $id));
        $row = $rowset->current();
        if (!$row) {
            throw new \Exception("Could not find row $id");
        }
        return $row;
    }

    public function saveClient(Client $client)
    {
        $data = array(
            'familyname' => $client->familyname,
            'businessname' => $client->businessname,
        );

        $id =  (int) $client(id);
        if($id==0){
            $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
        } else {
        if($this->getClient($id)){
            $this->tableGateway->update($data, array('id' => $id));
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('Client id does not exist');
        }
    }
}
```

}

My `ClientController.php` is as follows:

```
namespace Client\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Helper\ViewModel;

class ClientController extends AbstractActionController
{
protected $clientTable;

public function getClientTable()
{
    if(!$this->clientTable){
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->clientTable = $sm->get('Client\Model\ClientTable');
    }
    return $this->clientTable;
}

public function indexAction()
{
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'client' => $this->clientTable->fetchAll(),
    ));
}

public function addAction()
{
    return array();
}

public function editAction()
{
    return array();
}    

}
```

Last but not least, the view class is as follows:

```
<?php
$title = 'Client List';
$this->headtitle($title);
?>

<h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h1>
<p>
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('client', array('action'=>'add'));?>">Add New Client</a>
</p>

<table class="table">
<tr>
<th>Family Name</th>
<th>Business Name</th>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>

<?php foreach ($client as $client) : ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $this->escapehtml($client->familyname);?></td>
<td><?php echo $this->escapehtml($client->busienssname);?></td>
<td>
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('client', array('action'=>'edit', 
'id'=>$client->$id));?>">Edit</a>
</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

I've added the Client module to `application.config.php` as well.  Can someone suggest a some ways to remedy my issue where the Client index view is not rendering?

Update:  Note that the contents of `layout.phtml` are rendering.  However, the `index.phtml` in my `/module/client/view/client/client` contains the markup to add or edit a client which is not rendering.

Update 2:  I failed to mention that I used the Skeleton Application as basis for this app.  Not sure if there are configuration changes in it that are causing my issue?

Update 3:  I started this application with the intent to use Doctrine2 ORM.  However, it has been decided to just use ZendDbAdpater instead.  I removed Doctrine ORM from the application config.  Could my issue be caused by remnant Doctrine code in the project?  If so, what files and folders need to be removed to completely remove Doctrine 2 from the application?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not rendering'? Do you get a blank page? A 404 page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php foreach ($client as $client) : ?>
```

You are using the same variable again.

There might something wrong in your view script. You can wrap them in a try block and look at the error.

```
<?php

try {
    $title = 'Client List';
    $this->headtitle($title);
?>
<h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h1>
<p>

<a href="<?php echo $this->url('client', array('action'=>'add'));?>">Add New Client</a>

</p>


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Family Name</th>
        <th>Business Name</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
<?php foreach ($client as $client) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $this->escapehtml($client->familyname);?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->escapehtml($client->busienssname);?></td>
        <td>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->url('client', array('action'=>'edit', 
                'id'=>$client->$id));?>">Edit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>

<?php } catch (\Exception $e) {var_dump($e);} ?>
```